# Codeigniter : I can't log in to the officer dashboard, but in admin dashboard i can logged in

Tags: php, codeigniter

When I login as admin, it successfully walks in admin dashboard. But, when I login as the officer, the redirection to officer dashboard fails.

**Petugas.php**

application/controllers/Petugas.php

```html
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') or exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Petugas extends CI_Controller
{
    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        // cek session yang login, jika session status tidak sama dengan session petugas_login,maka halaman akan di alihkan kembali ke halaman login.   
        if ($this->session->userdata('status') != "petugas_login") {
            redirect(base_url() . 'login?alert=belum_login');
        }
    }
    function index()
    {
        $this->load->view('petugas/v_header');
        $this->load->view('petugas/v_index');
        $this->load->view('petugas/v_footer');
    }
}
```

**v_header.php**

Application/views/petugas/v_header.php

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Petugas - Sistem Informasi Perpustakaan MTS. Muhammadiyah 1 Depok</title>
    <!-- css bootstrap -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo base_url() . 'assets/css/bootstrap.css' ?>">

    <!-- css datatables -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo base_url() . 'assets/DataTables/datatables.css' ?>">

    <!-- icon font awesome -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo base_url() . 'assets/css/awesome/css/font-awesome.css' ?>">

    <!-- jquery dan bootstrap js -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url() . 'assets/js/jquery.js' ?>"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url() . 'assets/js/bootstrap.js' ?>"></script>

    <!-- js datatables -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url() . 'assets/DataTables/datatables.js' ?>"></script>
</head>

<body>

    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
        <div class="container-fluid"> <a class="navbar-brand" href="<?php echo base_url() . 'petugas'; ?>">Perpustakaan MTS.Muhammadiyah 1 Depok</a>
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" datatarget="#navbarText" aria-controls="navbarText" aria-expanded="false" arialabel="Toggle navigation"> <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarText">
                <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
                    <li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link" href="<?php echo base_url() . 'petugas'; ?>"><i class="fa fa-home"></i> Dashboard</a> </li>
                    <li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link" href="<?php echo base_url() . 'petugas/anggota'; ?>"><i class="fa fa-users"></i> Anggota</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link" href="<?php echo base_url() . 'petugas/buku'; ?>"><i class="fa fa-book"></i> Buku</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link" href="<?php echo base_url() . 'petugas/peminjaman'; ?>"><i class="fa fa-book"></i> Peminjaman</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link" href="<?php echo base_url() . 'petugas/peminjaman_laporan'; ?>"><i class="fa fa-book"></i> Laporan Peminjaman</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item"> <a href="<?php echo base_url() . 'petugas/ganti_password' ?>" class="navlink"><i class="fa fa-lock"></i> Ganti Password</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>

                <span class="navbar-text mr-3 text-center"> Halo, <?php echo $this->session->userdata('username'); ?> [Petugas] </span>

                <a href="<?php echo base_url() . 'petugas/logout' ?>" class="btn btn-outlinelight ml-1"><i class="fa fa-power-off"></i> KELUAR</a>
            </div>
        </div>

    </nav>

    <br />
    <br />
```

**v_index.php**

Application/views/petugas/v_index.php

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="jumbotron text-center">
        <div class="col-sm-8 mx-auto">
            <h1>Selamat datang!</h1>
            <p>Ini merupakan sistem informasi perpustakaan <b>MTS.Muhammadiyah 1 Depok</b>.</p>
            <p> Anda telah login sebagai <b><?php echo $this->session->userdata('nama'); ?></b> [petugas]. </p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
        <div class="card-header"> Dashboard </div>
        <div class="card-body"> Halo </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**v_footer.php**

Application/views/petugas/v_footer.php

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.table-datatable').DataTable();
    });
</script>
</body>

</html>
```

Login.php

application/controllers/Login.php

```html
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') or exit('No direct script access allowed');
class Login extends CI_Controller
{
    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }
    // menampilkan halaman login  
    public function index()
    {
        $this->load->view('v_login');
    }
    // validasi login  
    // function ini yang akan dieksekusi sebagai form handler dari form login kita tadi.
    public function login_aksi()
    {
        $username = $this->input->post('username');
        $password = $this->input->post('password');
        $sebagai = $this->input->post('sebagai');

        $this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username', 'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'required');

        if ($this->form_validation->run() != false) {
            $where = array(
                'username' => $username,
                'password' => md5($password)
            );

            if ($sebagai == "admin") {
                $cek = $this->m_data->cek_login('admin', $where)->num_rows();
                $data = $this->m_data->cek_login('admin', $where)->row();
                if ($cek > 0) {
                    $data_session = array(
                        'id' => $data->id,
                        'username' => $data->username,
                        'status' => 'admin_login'
                    );
                    $this->session->set_userdata($data_session);
                    redirect(base_url() . 'admin');
                } else {
                    redirect(base_url() . 'login?alert=gagal');
                }
            } else if ($sebagai == "petugas") {
                $cek = $this->m_data->cek_login('petugas', $where)->num_rows();
                $data = $this->m_data->cek_login('petugas', $where)->row();
                if ($cek > 0) {
                    $data_session = array(
                        'id' => $data->id,
                        'nama' => $data->nama,
                        'username' => $data->username,
                        'status' => 'petugas_login'
                    );
                    $this->session->set_userdata($data_session);
                    redirect(base_url() . 'petugas');
                } else {
                    redirect(base_url() . 'login?alert=gagal');
                }
            }
        } else {
            $this->load->view('v_login');
        }
    }
}
```

v_login.php

application/views/v_login.php

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Login - Sistem Informasi Perpustakaan MTS.Muhammadiyah 1 Depok</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo base_url() . 'assets/css/bootstrap.css' ?>">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url() . 'assets/js/jquery.js' ?>"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url() . 'assets/js/bootstrap.js' ?>"></script>
</head>

<body class="bg-dark">

    <div class="container">
        <br /><br /><br /><br />

        <h3 class="font-weight-normal text-center text-white">SISTEM INFORMASI</h3>
        <h2 class="font-weight-normal text-center text-white mb-5"><b>PERPUSTAKAAN</b></h2>

        <div class="col-md-4 offset-md-4">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <?php
                    if (isset($_GET['alert'])) {
                        if ($_GET['alert'] == "gagal") {
                            echo "<div class='alert alert-danger font-weight-bold text-center'>LOGIN GAGAL!</div>";
                        } else if ($_GET['alert'] == "belum_login") {
                            echo "<div class='alert alert-danger font-weight-bold text-center'>SILAHKAN LOGIN TERLEBIH DULU!</div>";
                        } else if ($_GET['alert'] == "logout") {
                            echo "<div class='alert alert-success font-weight-bold text-center'>ANDA TELAH LOGOUT!</div>";
                        }
                    }
                    ?>

                    <h4 class="font-weight-bold text-center mb-3 mt-3">LOGIN</h4>

                    <!-- validasi error -->
                    <?php echo validation_errors(); ?>

                    <form method="post" action="<?php echo base_url() . 'login/login_aksi'; ?>">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="username">Username</label>
                            <input name="username" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Masukan username">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="password">Password</label>
                            <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Masukkan Password">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="sebagai">Login Sebagai : </label>
                            <select name="sebagai" class="form-control">
                                <option value="admin">Admin</option>
                                <option value="petugas">Petugas</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Login</button>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: error yang didapat kaya gimana?

Comment: di text editor ga ada error pak, cuma saya mau login sebagai petugas perpustakaan tidak bisa login.

Comment: Di Code Editor ga ada error pak, kendalanya ketika mau login sebagai Petugas perpustakaan tidak bisa masuk ke dashboard petugas.
tapi untuk login sebagai admin perpustakaan bisa masuk ke dashboard pak.

Comment: tidak bisa loginnya itu ke redirect ke halaman login lagi apa gimana?

Comment: iya betul langsung ke halaman login lagi. dan ada tulisan 'login gagal!'
sebelumnya saya sudah buat akun untuk petugas perpus melalui admin. agar petugas bisa login.

Comment: saya gak pake CI sih, tapi coba di controller loginnya, cek isi masing masing variable yg dipakai untuk kondisi, contoh : `$sebagai = $this->input->post('sebagai');` coba  `die($sebagai);`  terus kondisi pas cek uname dan password `$cek = $this->m_data->cek_login('petugas', $where)->num_rows();`  coba `die($cek)`

Comment: bagaimana? `$cek`-nya ada isinya tidak?

Comment: ok, `die($sebagai)` nya hapus lagi, sekarang sisakan yang `die($cek)`

Comment: nilainya blank putih pak.

Comment: berarti $cek nya kosong ya, makannya yang dieksekusi itu else-nya. Tugasnya sekarang adalah benerin `$this->m_data->cek_login('petugas', $where)->num_rows();` supaya dia berhasil ngeluarin data yang sesuai

Comment: baik pak, saya liat dulu

Answer (score 0):

Please check what you are saving in session while making the user login.

In your "Petugas"  **controller** **constructor** you seem to be checking the status parameter saved in session (that must be saved while making the user login your app/site),

Please check what value is saved out there.

Is it "petugas_login" saved in session **status** parameter.

Comment: Thanks for that. 
I already check. please chek again in Login.php